# Windows Form app won't run at startup but will run manually

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, group-policy

I'm attempting to run an app on startup on a Dell laptop running Windows 10 Enterprise. It is written in C# using Visual Studio. The app is meant to run with administrator privileges. If I manually start the app, it works just fine. When I attempt to run it automatically using local group policy editor, it gives me the following error on login: "This application could not be started."

I looked up that error and wound up at the following link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2715633/shim-errors-for-the-net-framework-version-and-platform-support. It said: "The app is not configured in a way that makes it possible to determine the appropriate version of the .NET Framework runtime. The corresponding shim code is SHIM_NOVERSION_FOUND."

I used information found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed to determine which .NET frameworks were installed on the target device. There were a few, including version 4.0.

I added a config file to my project using instructions from the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5.

When I rebuild the project and try to run it on the target machine, I get the same error as before.

NOTE: The target computer is under a group policy which may or may not be affecting the app. We don't know.

Comment: What framework are you targeting and what does your app.config look like?

Comment: "meant to run with administrator privileges" is surely the problem.  You can't prompt the user with the UAC consent dialog at startup, he'll have no idea why the prompt appeared.  So this is actively suppressed by the OS.  Only workaround is use two apps, one you can start automatically, with a button that starts the second app and thus triggers the consent dialog.  Or a scheduled task or service.

Comment: The app is used to signout the laptop. It's not meant to ask the user's permission, though I'm still figuring that part out. It should have admin rights by default, without querying the user about it. If they don't enter their name, it signs them back out of Windows. The app also blocks access to task manager by way of the registry.

Comment: Does that matter? If I get it working correctly so that the user isn't confronted with the UAC dialog, will that fix the issue? Or do I still need to start it from another app?

Comment: Like Hans said, set up the launch through task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

My ultimate solution for this problem was to build an installer for the program instead of just copying the release version over to the laptops manually